# i can't ping a computer but remoting into it works (powershell enter-pssession)

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

i have a rather basic Question:
I was setting up a Test-Computer (WinServer2k12) outside of my Domain-network but in the same subnet.
`Ping` via ip or name both failed (same with `test-connection 123.11.23.2`) - ... host could not be found... 
... AND Rdp-Connection fails (`mstsc /v: 123.21.23.2`)
... BUT it IS possible to `enter-pssession` into it!! (`etsn 123.21.23.2 -cred admin`)
I'm curious about it because i observed this behaviour in a win7/XP-Workgroup-Environment before.
What technology ist `enter-pssession` using and (how) can i make use of it (e.g. when ping is failing).
Or am i thinking in the wrong direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a firewall at destination PC blocking pings and RDP (if not enabled) and WSMAN port is open and listening. You should probably employ `portqry` check against WSMAN ports (TCP 5985, 5986 - the latter is WSMAN over HTTPS) and if that port is "Listening", try connecting via `New-PSSession`.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i enabled RDP in the sconfig-tool on the server and it is activated (whereas i wasn't able to change the "ping-reply" option via sconfig - it jumped right back to the main-menu when selected) - but i will test it, thanks for the hint

Comment: Look into firewall profile and enabled rules on the destination PC. You need to check incoming rules for ICMP (`File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)` rule) and RDP (`Remote Desktop` rule), these should be enabled in order for ICMP and/or RDP traffic to reach the system.

Comment: ok, so after i found an enabled the rule `get-netfirewallrule|?{$_.description -like "*ping*"}|ft name,displaygroup,action,direction,enabled,description -autosize;
Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name "fps-*"` ping replies instantly, same for "remotedesktop-" Rules ... yeah ... that was easy ... maybe to easy to find the solution... thank you very much!!